# How to return and access an object from a Javascript on a button post submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I am working on a Javascript that aims to return then manipulate an object from a clicked button. I am now stuck how can i get its object then process it on a post method. On my button I have this:

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit" form="form-add" id="export-btn" class="btn btn-small"  style="border-radius: 0;"><i class="fas fa-save"></i><span class="button-save"></span>Save</button>
```

and i have this javascript method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $TABLE = $('#table');
    var $BTN = $('#export-btn');
    var $EXPORT = $('#export');
        ...

        // A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
        jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
        jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

        $BTN.click(function () {
            var $rows = $TABLE.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
            var headers = [];
            var data = [];

          // Get the headers (add special header logic here)
          $($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {
            headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
          });

          // Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
          $rows.each(function () {
            var $td = $(this).find('td');
            var h = {};

            // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
            headers.forEach(function (header, i) {
                h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();   
            });

            data.push(h);
        });

          // Output the result
          $EXPORT.text(JSON.stringify(data));

          return data;
        });
</script>
```

and on top of my page I have this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   echo "Test";
   // Process here the object
}
```

but **How can i access those data**, since `$EXPORT.text(JSON.stringify(data));` output a JSON, that looks like this `[{"id":"1","Val":"Sample","data":"Sample Date"}]` on my paragraph tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't post data from paragraph.
Create hidden input in the form and assign the data to it.

```
$(this).append($("<input />", { name : "foo", value : data,  type : "hidden" }))
```

Comment: I have done this before, but i am not so sure if it is acceptable in the real world scenario. That is why instead of assigning into some tag I am trying to return an object in the function.

Comment: I mean, is it not cheating that i just put the result into a tag then access it?

Comment: This is the way you should do it. Note the Definition and Usage in 
 - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp